# Avoid link on the figure caption as well How

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

On my input xml i have the figures, images and its cross-linking text in many places. When I try to code cross link using  tag, it does cross link on the caption text also. But, I need to code cross link everywhere except on the caption text.

```
<par class="para">In addition to the core publications, there is also a complementary set of ITIL publications providing guidance specific to industry sectors, organization types, operating models and technology architectures on `Figure 1.1`.</par>

        <par class="figurecaption">Figure 1.1  The ITIL service lifecycle</par>
        <par class="image">gr000001</par>
```

My xslt code goes

```
<xsl:template match="text()" exclude-result-prefixes="html">
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(Chapter|Figure|Table|Appendix)\s(\d+|[A-Z])(\.)?(\d+)?|(www.[^ ]+)|(http://[^ ]+)|(Section|section)\s(\d)\.(\d+)(\.)?(\d+|\d)?(\.)?(\d)?" flags="x">
<xsl:matching-substring>        
<a><xsl:attribute name="href">
```

.....

it produces the result

```
<p>In addition to the core publications, there is also a complementary set of ITIL publications providing guidance specific to industry sectors, organization types, operating models and technology architectures on `<a href="chapter1.html#Fig1">Figure 1.1</a>`.</p>

    <p><a href="chapter1.html#Fig1">Figure 1.1</a>  The ITIL service lifecycle</p>
    <img src="gr000001"/>
```

But, I need

```
<p>In addition to the core publications, there is also a complementary set of ITIL publications providing guidance specific to industry sectors, organization types, operating models and technology architectures on `<a href="chapter1.html#Fig1">Figure 1.1</a>`.</p>

<p>`Figure 1.1`  The ITIL service lifecycle</p>
        <img src="gr000001"/>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking, but how about:

```
<xsl:template match="text()[parent::par/@class='para']">
```

That way, `par` elements where `@class='figurecaption'` are excluded from the string analysis.

If needed, you can then write a second template that matches the text of figure captions and manipulate it separately:

```
<xsl:template match="text()[parent::par/@class='figurecaption']">
```

Comment: @All I have started to have the topic at university, but look at the views on SO! Have you ever used `XSLT` in production? Thanks

Comment: This is slightly off-topic of course - but since I'm writing anyway: Yes, most of the XSLT answerers have built or maintained productive systems that make use of XSLT, I'd daresay.

Comment: Hi, I based the assumption that the question is kinda private on the views! Could we have a small [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47231/xslt)? Thanks