# Template with cross-link that should not need cross link

Tags: xslt

I have a problem on matching scenarios, I am using my templates as follows on the xslt, but i am not getting the correct output. Actually, now, this xslt produces cross-link to the caption text also, but, it should not do for table and figure caption. My intention is this should produce cross-link except table caption and figure caption.

In my xslt, I have this scenarios,

```
<xsl:template match="text()[../@class != 'tablecaption' or ../../@class != 'tablecaption' or ../@class != 'figurecaption']" exclude-result-prefixes="html">
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(Chapter|Figure|Table|Appendix)\s(\d+|[A-Z])(\.)?(\d+)?|(www.[^ ]+)|(http://[^ ]+)|(Section|section)\s(\d)\.(\d+)(\.)?(\d+|\d)?(\.)?(\d)?" flags="x">
<xsl:matching-substring>
                <a>
<xsl:attribute name="href">
<xsl:variable name="x1" select="regex-group(1)"/>
<xsl:variable name="x2" select="regex-group(2)"/>
<xsl:variable name="x4" select="regex-group(4)"/>
<xsl:variable name="x5" select="regex-group(5)"/>
<xsl:variable name="x6" select="regex-group(6)"/>
<xsl:variable name="x7" select="regex-group(7)"/>
```

as per my goal, this xslt should not provide cross-link here. it does the same here

```
 <par class="tablecaption"><inline style="list-style-type: decimal; ">Table 3.4  Examples of extremely reactive and proactive behaviour</inline></par>
```

this should be transformed to 
`<p class="tablecaption">Table 3.4  Examples of extremely reactive and proactive behaviour</p>`, this is ok

Here(below), as per my goal this xslt should not provide cross-link to the below also. But, as of now, it is providing cross-link to the below one, but, it should not.

```
<par class="tablecaption">Table 3.3  Examples of extremely reactive and proactive behaviour</inline></par>
```

this should be transformed to

```
<p class="tablecaption">Table 3.3  Examples of extremely reactive and proactive behaviour</p>
```

but, it is transfromed as follows

```
<p class="tablecaption"><a href="#tab1">Table 3.3</a>  Examples of extremely reactive and proactive behaviour</p>
```

Why it is? Any idea pls

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoid link on the figure caption as well How](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698287/avoid-link-on-the-figure-caption-as-well-how)

Comment: @Muller: Kindly read my question carefully. I am NOT asking the repeated question. My PROBLEM is entirely different. I am again insisting you kindly read my question, so that you can get my problem.

Comment: That's why it says "possible duplicate". Please add more context to your question, that is, more XML input and the entire XSLT stylesheet if possible.

Comment: Perhaps the 'or's in ../@class != 'tablecaption' or ../../@class != 'tablecaption' or ../@class != 'figurecaption' need to be changed to 'and's

Comment: @PollyShaw: I tried the same, but, it did not work.

Comment: Well ../@class != 'tablecaption' or ../@class != 'figurecaption' is always going to return true.

Comment: I already told you that separate templates are a better idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698287/avoid-link-on-the-figure-caption-as-well-how/21698608#21698608

Comment: Hi All, I tried by using 'text()[not(../@class = 'tablecaption' or ../../@class = 'tablecaption' or ../@class = 'figurecaption')]', It is working. Thanks for all.